# issues with jQuery accept

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Firstly apologises if this already on stack overflow.  I have 3 blocks, one of these blocks need to be dragged into the target segment. unfortunately when I drag any of the 3 blocks I the code executes. If the user drags the incorrect block I simply want it to do nothing. I am new to coding, but from what I've read the following:

```
accept: "#Proof";
```

should work, however it seems not. Help is greatly appreciated. Please note I must do this in jQuery as it's for an education project.

Many thanks

```
  $(".drop").draggable();

  $("#Proof").draggable();

  $("#target").droppable({
      accept: "#Proof";
    drop: function (event, ui){
      $("#Proof").html("Success!!<br> Please now press submit");
      $("#target").css("background-color", "#00cc00");
      $(".falseTarget").css("background-color", "#00cc00");
      $(".drop").hide();
      $("#Proof").draggable('disable');
    }  
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo issue in your code.

```
$("#target").droppable({
    accept: "#Proof"; // <-- replace ';' by ','
    drop: function (event, ui) {...}
});
```